# Maximum size of the function in lambda@edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have two serverless functions that are executed in lambda@edge given two cloudfront events: `viewer-request` and `origin-response`, I want to implement a nodejs `sharp` library to scale these images on the fly given some parameters received in the querystring.

The problem is that when I install the mentioned dependency, the deployment package is greater than 9MB, and according to the edge documentation, the functions must be <= 1MB.

Can I do something about it to fix this?

This is my serverless.yml file.

```yaml
service: scale-otf

provider:
  name: aws
  timeout: 5
  memorySize: 128
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  iam:
    role: LambdaEdgeRole

plugins:
  - serverless-lambda-edge-pre-existing-cloudfront

functions:
  request:
    handler: dist/request.handler
    events:
      - preExistingCloudFront:
          distributionId: <id-of-my-existing-distribution>
          eventType: viewer-request
          pathPattern: '*'
          includeBody: false

  response:
    handler: dist/response.handler
    events:
      - preExistingCloudFront:
          distributionId: <id-of-my-existing-distribution>
          eventType: origin-response
          pathPattern: '*'
          includeBody: false

package:
  patterns:
    - '!**/**'
    - 'dist/**'

# Create a Lambda@Edge function via the wizard in Lambda Console
# and then copied the role and pasted it here
resources:
  Resources:
    LambdaEdgeRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - edgelambda.amazonaws.com
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: LambdaEdgeExecutionRole
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                  Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
```

Comment: *I want to implement a nodejs sharp library to scale these images on the fly given some parameters received in the querystring* - what images? Like, graphical images? Are they part of your deployment package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use sharp on lambda@edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096160/use-sharp-on-lambdaedge)

Comment: FYI: there are a lot of existing resources on exactly the problem of using Sharp w/ Lambda@Edge. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767809/use-lambda-edgewith-cloudfront-trigger-to-resize-images-on-fly), [this AWS doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/resizing-images-with-amazon-cloudfront-lambdaedge-aws-cdn-blog/), [this github issue](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2073)